# Why is my list showing up twice

Tags: latex3, expl3

Why does the following code result in my list being strangely, but not quite duplicated?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ae_number_clist
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_selection:nn #1#2 
  {
    \clist_map_inline:Nn {#2} { \clist_gput_right:Nn \l_ae_number_clist { $##1$ } }
    \clist_use:Nn \l_ae_number_clist { \hspace*{#1} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeQMakeSelection}{ O{1em}m }
  {
    \_ae_selection:nn {#1}{#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\aeQMakeSelection{-2,3,4,-5}

\end{document}
```

Also, I don't understand how I can build my list without making a *global* definition when my list should only be local.

Comment: @cgnieder But when I do that, the list is not formatted correctly.  Notice how the negative sign disappears from the two.  But the bigger tell-tale sign is that the spacing hasn't been applied.  Nor is anything in math mode as you can tell from the negative 5.

Comment: Ach!  I've been blind then too.  :*(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `\clist_map_inline:nn`, not `\clist_map_inline:Nn`; the former expects an explicit clist as argument, the latter a clist variable.

However, there are other weak points: the clist variable `\l_ae_number_clist` will be augmented for each call of `\aeQMakeSelection`, that doesn't seem wanted (and you're using global assignments to a local variable).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ae_number_clist
\cs_new:Npn \ae_selection:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin:
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#2} { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_ae_number_clist { $##1$ } }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_ae_number_clist { \hspace*{#1} }
  \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeQMakeSelection}{ O{1em}m }
 {
  \ae_selection:nn {#1}{#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\aeQMakeSelection{-2,3,4,-5}

\end{document}
```

The function `\ae_selection:nn` shouldn't be private, because it's at the outer programming level, used by an `xparse` macro, but this is a stylistic decision.

Here's a different approach using sequences that are more efficient than clists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_ae_selection_seq
\seq_new:N \l_ae_output_seq

\cs_new:Npn \ae_selection:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ae_selection_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_ae_output_seq \l_ae_selection_seq { \exp_not:n { $##1$ } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_ae_output_seq { \hspace*{#1} }
  \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeQMakeSelection}{ O{1em}m }
 {
  \ae_selection:nn {#1}{#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\aeQMakeSelection{-2,3,4,-5}

\end{document}
```

---

Let's see what went wrong; `\clist_map_inline:Nn` is defined as

```
\clist_map_inline:Nn:
\protected\long macro:#1#2->\clist_if_empty:NF #1{...}
```

Then we need to see `\clist_if_empty:NF`:

```
\clist_if_empty:NF:
\long macro:#1->\if_meaning:w #1\c_empty_tl \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi: \c_zero {}
```

Now, `\if_meaning:w` is just `\ifx`, so your call `\aeQMakeSelection{-2,3,4,-5}` translates into

```
\_ae_selection:nn {1em}{-2,3,4,-5}
```

that eventually becomes

```
\clist_if_empty:NF -2,3,4,-5{...}
```

and so we get

```
\if_meaning:w -\c_empty_tl \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi: \c_zero {} ...
```

that compares `-` to `\c_empty_tl` so the conditional follows the false branch, giving `\prg_return_false:` and all goes very wrong.

The fact that the argument is specified as `N`, doesn't mean that TeX balks if the next token is `{`: TeX follows its rules and takes the whole `-2,3,4,-5` as its argument.

Comment: Thank you for adding the point about *private* functions.  I wasn't aware that LaTeX3 made that distinction.  Sorry about the global declaration, it was only there because I thought briefly that somehow the `\clist_map_inline:Nn` was localized.  I would've caught that mistake had I noticed I wrote "N" instead of "n".  :(

Comment: But what I'm wondering is why I didn't get an error when I passed the wrong type of argument to `\clist_map_inline:Nn`.  Is there a reason `expl3` didn't catch that I was violating the argument type?

Comment: @A.Ellett I've added some analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up.  It help explains why the initial `-` was lost in the *apparent* output, and why LaTeX was happy to work with what I passed it.